# Quicktime video not being saved on Catalina

Tags: quicktime

After starting a video the `Stop` button is being displayed as usual:

[image]

I then click the stop button ( *by the way is there a shortcut for stop??* ) and here is where things are broken: there is no offer to save the buffered video!

Here is the menu: notably the `Save` is disabled.

[image]

So what has happened to `Quicktime` - and how to fix this?

Comment: What are the options in "export as" ? Also how do you start the video recording ? in Quicktime, or via cmd + shift + 5 ?

Comment: video is started by the button click.  "Export as" is not relevant: needs to be "Save as". In any case all of its items are also disabled.